# Does Azure DevOps support API to query git repo hosted in Azure Devops?

Tags: azure-devops

If I host my code repo in Azure DevOps, does Azure DevOps provide any API (e.g. HTTP API) that allows me to query the history (commits) of a specific file?

If azure devops does not provide that, does any git hosting service have such a feature?

Comment: Did you look at the extensive REST API documentation? Stack Overflow is not a substitute for doing your own research.

Comment: We can query the history of a specific file, NC11's answer is right, just specify the searchCriteria.itemPath parameter.  For example : `GET https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repo id}/commits?searchCriteria.itemPath=azure-pipelines-2.yml`, So, you could mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a link to the Azure DevOps git commit API docs:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get%20commits?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1

Specifically you would need to make use of the searchCriteria.itemPath parameter